# SonicWALL SSL VPN HTTP Bookmarks

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

We have a SonicWALL NSA 240. I'd like to use the Virtual Office SSL VPN to add a HTTP (web) bookmark....but when I click Add Bookmark, all I see is RDP, VNC, SSH, and Telnet.

Is there some license I'm missing to be able to add this? How can I add an HTTP Bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the built-in SSL VPN function on your SonicWALL NSA is really designed for remote access connectivity (mostly used to replace the old Global VPN Client IPSec VPN connections).  IT is not designed to provide a "typical" SSL VPN portal where users can login and access applications (e.g. internal/external HTTP & HTTPS websites.)

If you want users to have that kind of access to web applications you will need a [SonicWALL SRA appliance](http://www.firewalls.com/sonicwall/sra).  In short, the SRA give your users access to many of the common SSL VPN portal features.